# How to preview images in folder's icons?

Tags: icons, xfce, filemanager, thunar, previews

I'm looking for a solution to preview images or videos of a folder in it's icon to identify easily. This feature has been present in Windows ever since but for some reason, I am unable to find it in Linux desktop environments. I have Xubuntu 16.04. If you can help then it will be great.
I'm attaching a sample image for proper understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by Anderson doesn't really fit to the question. **File** previews weren't asked and are indeed part of Nautilus (haven't used the other ones, so can only tell about Nautilus).

To get **folder** previews/thumbnails with Nautilus you may try [Cover Thumbnailer](https://projects.flogisoft.com/cover-thumbnailer/).
It's working for me good with Music and Pictures folders and pretty unreliable with "Other" folders, but with its settings gui, you're free to add more folders to the first ones and so bypass last one.
Be aware that Cover Thumbnailer is not part of the official repositories. Using its ppa is the easiest way to install it.

Answer (score 1):

Image previews are available in:

- Dolphin (KDE DE), select `View->View Mode->Icons`;
- Nautilus (GNOME DE), select the grid of dots in the upper right (`View Items as Grid of Icons`);
- Caja (MATE DE), select `Edit->Preferences->Preview`, `Other Previewable Files`, `Show thumbnails` to `Always` (also you can set `Only for files smaller than` to size needed).
- Thunar (Xfce DE), select `View->View as Icons`.

Comment: I neither use dolphin nor Nautilus. One solution can be to download and install those file managers but can you provide above desktop environments oriented solution then it will be even better.

Comment: @muhammad_ahmad_mujtaba Xubuntu has Xfce4 desktop which comes with Thunar afaik. If this answer doesn't work for you, what file manager are you using?